# Do auto-rejections of edits to orphan tag wikis count against me?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I edited the wiki of a tag that had only one question, and then somebody decided that the tag should not exist (they're probably right), they removed it from the question, and so the tag went away. The Suggested Edits review task was marked as "no longer reviewable" a couple hours later, without getting the necessary two Reject votes to dismiss it (not even an auto-rejection from Community). My count of rejected edits went up.

Was that a real rejection? Could such events impair my ability to edit tag wikis? I have more than 2K rep, but less than 20K.

Comment: It's probably the same as if a post is deleted while it got pending edits (tag wiki is a post, somewhere behind the scenes), need to look into it, maybe there's something here in MSE about it already.